Cartoon movie about three kids running away from something evil
There isn't a lot of information I can give, but, I DO remember two particular scenes in the movie: 

The Villain (or something) thinks he/she found the main characters in an Indian tent but it turns out that they were just silhouettes made out of snow 
The kids are on a small boat (or a canoe) while the ice is forming back together behind them. 
The movie takes place during winter, it was (probably) a sequel or based on an animated series, the ending scene has two birds flying around while the main characters are talking and then it fades to black. 
It was dubbed in my country, so I don't know the origin of the movie.
I believe the movie was made somewhere around late 90's/early 00's.
As for the characters I cant remember how they looked like and I
think it was two girls and a boy. The animation wasn't anything
spectacular I think it was low budget something like the Rudolf the
red nosed reindeer (not the stop motion one) animated movie.

EDIT: !!!MOVIE IDENTITY FOUND IT WAS "THE LEGEND OF THE NORTH WIND" !!!!

Hi! Do you know the approximate year\decade of release? When did you see it? Do you remember what the characters looked like (or at least their gender)? And what type of animation was it?

I believe the movie was made somewhere around late 90's/early 00's. As for the characters I cant remember how they looked like and I think it was two girls and a boy. The animation wasn't anything spectacular I think it was low budget something like the Rudolf the red nosed reindeer animated movie. Hope this helps

Please edit the additional info from your comment into your question. By something like Rudolph, do you mean stop-motion animation—as opposed to computer or classical (drawn) animation?

@Gloger If you've found the movie, you can add it as an answer and then mark it as accepted.

MOVIE IDENTITY FOUND IT WAS "THE LEGEND OF THE NORTH WIND"
